# Is it possible to perform a One-To-Many foreign-key JOIN with criteria-builder?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, persistence, criteria

Assume the following two database models:

**Owner**: `id`, `name`

**Pet**: `id`, `name`, `owner`

*where `Pet.owner` is a foreign key to the `Owner`'s `id`*

---

Can you query all users with a name similar to *Denise* that have pets with a name similar to *Bella*, using the [criteria builder join](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/package-summary.html)?

The SQL query would look similar to:

```
SELECT o FROM Owner o JOIN Pet p ON o.id = p.owner
WHERE o.name LIKE 'Denise' AND p.name LIKE 'Bella'
```

> Sorting options will also be used, so it is only possible to use the criteria queries, instead of creating a typed query directly (and setting parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure it is. You can do with Criteria API everything you can do with JPQL.

Read a tutorial: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Your query will look like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Owner> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Owner.class);

Root<Pet> pet = criteriaQuery.from(Pet.class);

Join<Pet, Owner> owner = pet.join(Pet_.owner);
criteriaQuery
        .select(owner)
        .where(criteriaBuilder
            .and(
                 criteriaBuilder.like(owner.get(Owner_.name), "Denise"), 
                 criteriaBuilder.like(pet.get(Pet_.name), "Bella")));

List<Owner> resultList = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Comment: I have been reading through a lot of documentation and tutorials (this one included) and have not yet found the functionality for one-to-many without changing a model, and without using a manual string JOIN query. (Only many-to-one or via a List<T> or similar in the owner model)

Comment: I added the working query. as you can see you start with the Pet and then join the owner but select the owner as result. If my answer was helpful I would appreciate if you could accept as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: _Sorry, was on holiday_ - This looks exactly like what I need, I couldn't find it anywhere! Thanks, I will try it out now...